# Don't know how to get select parameters from a form to a database with jsp

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, jsp, select

```
<div id="crear">
    <h1>Crear nota</h1>
    <div id="formcrear">
        <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="titulo-div">
            <label for="titulo"><strong>T&iacute;tulo de la nota</strong></label>
            <input id="titulo" type="text" value="" name="titulo" maxlength="100" required="required"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="categoria-div">
            Categoria:
            <select name="categoria-option" id="select1">
            <option value="1">Hola
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addCategoria()">
        </div>
        <div class="color-div">
            Color:
            <select id="select_color" name="select_color" onchange="changeColor()" onchange="showSelected()">
                <option value="white">Blanco</option>
                <option value="red">Rojo</option>
                <option value="blue">Azul   </option>
                <option value="green">Verde</option>
                <option value="yellow">Amarillo</option>
                <option value="pink">Rosa</option>
                <option value="orange">Naranja</option>
            </select>
            +
            <input type="color" id="color-id"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="imagen-div">
            <label for="urlimagen"><strong>URL de la imagen</strong></label>
            <input id="urlimagen" type="text" value="" name="urlimagen"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="nota-div">
            <label for="nota"><strong>Nota</strong></label>
            <textarea id="nota" name="nota" cols="100%" rows="100%"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="boton" id="enviarnota" type="submit" value="Crear" name="enviarnota"></input>
        <input class="boton" id="limpiar" type="reset" value="Limpiar datos" name="limpiar"></input>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

 <% try{

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dit";
    String user = "dit";
    String pass = "dit";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

    if(conn != null){

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String cad = "INSERT INTO notas(nombre_usuario, titulo, nota, urlimagen, categoria, color) VALUES ('"+session.getAttribute("nombre")+"','"+request.getParameter("titulo")+"','"+request.getParameter("nota")+"','"+request.getParameter("urlimagen")+"','"+request.getParameter("categoria")+"','"+request.getParameter("select_color")+"')";
        int n = st.executeUpdate(cad);

        st.close();
        conn.close();

}else{
    out.println("<script>alert('error')</script>");
}


 } catch (SQLException e) {
  out.println("Excepción SQL Exception: " + e.getMessage() + " fichero: crearnota.jsp");
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 %>
```

I have a problem with saving the fields "categoria" and "color", I need to save the value of these 2 field into my database but I dont know how to acces their values, I have tried using `request.getParameter()` but it didn't work, I've spent a lot of time trying to find a solution but I have'nt, can someone help me please?

`addCategoria()` adds a "categoria" to the option field and works correctly and `changeColor()` chages the color of a text and works correctly too.

Comment: Your select field name is `categoria-option` but you are trying access the same using `categoria` .Change that to `request.getParameter("categoria-option")` .